# How to properly specify which function goes from which file?

Tags: c++

The question is about organizing your own code.

Let's say I have multiple *.cpp and corresponding headers to them and I use some functions from these in another parts of program code.
After some time passes I may start to forget which header and cpp a certain function goes from and looking at a simple

```
    func();
```

tells absolutely nothing.

I can only think of using namespaces so I can later write

```
    Module::func();
```

Any other ways? I heard using many namespaces isn't a good practice and a bunch of my projects have more than 5-10 cpp's and headers

Comment: With any good IDE: right click, "go to definition".

Comment: @immibis Yes, this works, but you get to do some unncessary clicks in order to figure it out instead of seeing it right away

Comment: OOP ?!
If you can't change your project to OOP, namespaces are most solid approach.
`I heard using many namespaces isn't a good practice` Where do you heard it ?

Comment: @AramKocharyan Somewhere around stackoverflow. OOP is a possibility, but I can only see my code as 1-3 classes where one of them will have a ton of methods. How will I move method declarations/definitions to different files later? I'd say this would be even worse to work with. Plus I don't like declaring classes everytime just to use any of their methods

Comment: @user3035035 If so, you can freely use namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your project to OOP.

Every `.cpp` file will represent single class.
In any part of programm you can see to what object belong called method.

If changing to OOP is problem, you can/must use namespaces.
Namespaces only can 'affect' compile-time performance, no other issues can come with it.

Comment: Note, this is not what OOP actually means.